# Как сделать switch для элементов типа Enum

Tags: java, android, enum

Есть класс типа `Enum` и я хочу для него сделать `switch` но мне говорит `constant expression required`.

Т.е. таким способом работает

```
    if (item.getType() == ItemType.TEXT) {

    }
```

а вот так не работает

```
    switch (item.getType()){
        case ItemType.TEXT:
    }
```

и так тоже на работает

```
    switch (item.getType().toString()){
        case String.valueOf(ItemType.TEXT):
    }
```

Вот сам класс `enum`

```
public enum ItemType {
   TEXT,PHOTO,EMPTY;
}
```

Comment: Не скажу насчёт enum (сам не понимаю почему не работает `case ItemType.TEXT`), но switch со String появился относительно недавно. Наверное у Вас андроид не той системы. С другой стороны вызов `String.valueOf(ItemType.TEXT)` `constant expression` ну никак не назовёшь. Надо писать `"TEXT"`

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Делайте так:

```
switch(item.getType())
{
    case TEXT:

    break;
    case PHOTO:

    break;
    case EMPTY:

    break;
}
```

Comment: Перед `swith` при необходимости отдельно проверить ещё один `case`: `if (item.getType() == null)  { ... }`

Comment: отлично, это работает